# Deriving instances with default implementation in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have the following code which compiles

```hs
class Foo m where
  foo :: String -> m Int

class (Foo m) => Bar m where
  bar :: String -> m Int
  bar id = foo id

instance Foo IO where
  foo _ = return 0

instance Bar IO where

quux :: IO Int
quux = foo ""

baz :: IO Int
baz = bar ""
```

However, when I comment out the line `instance Bar IO where`

```hs
class Foo m where
  foo :: String -> m Int

class (Foo m) => Bar m where
  bar :: String -> m Int
  bar id = foo id

instance Foo IO where
  foo _ = return 0

-- instance Bar IO where

quux :: IO Int
quux = foo ""

baz :: IO Int
baz = bar ""
```

I get the error

```
    • No instance for (Bar IO) arising from a use of ‘bar’
    • In the expression: bar ""
      In an equation for ‘baz’: baz = bar ""
```

Is there a GHC extension which would derive an instance for `Bar IO`?

I have an intuition that this should be possible, especially since I could have such an instances derived if I implemented those typeclasses in Scala with implicits.

Comment: If you receive an answer to your question that leads to another problem, please don't edit your question to completely change it.  That makes the old answer(s) invalid which causes confusion and reduces the value of the site to others who come along with similar questions in the future.  I've rolled back the edits and would ask you to please submit your revised question as a brand new one.  Thanks!

Comment: Question score may be a meta-effect of discussion: [Is an admittedly copied answer which does not add any useful detail (that just adds noise) an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400763)

Answer (score 9):

In this declaration:

```
class (Foo m) => Bar m where
    -- ...
```

The `Foo m` is a *requirement* for a `Bar` instance to be written, not a method for deriving one. *Even if* you write an instance with an implementation of `bar`, you won't be able to make a `Bar` instance without a `Foo` instance in scope.

If you want to provide an *instance* of `Bar`, you will have to have an `instance` declaration somewhere.

You can, however, say:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
instance (Foo m) => Bar m where
```

and you'll have a `Bar IO`.

Comment: If you are okay with `instance Foo m => Bar m`, then in my opinion you should not create the `Bar` class in the first place (see the second half of my answer for the alternative).

Answer (score 3):

For empty instance declarations, there is `DeriveAnyClass`; this is fairly convenient when used with types where you control the data declaration. For `IO`, you don't, and so would also need `StandaloneDeriving`. At that point, the boilerplate is significantly longer than writing the empty instance yourself, but for posterity, here's what it looks like:

```
{-# Language DeriveAnyClass #-}
{-# Language StandaloneDeriving #-}

deriving instance Bar IO

-- all the remaining code is copied from the question

class Foo m where
  foo :: String -> m Int

class (Foo m) => Bar m where
  bar :: String -> m Int
  bar id = foo id

instance Foo IO where
  foo _ = return 0
```

That said, I am suspicious of the `Bar` class. Are you sure you want a separate class for `bar`, and don't just want a function that uses the `Foo` class directly? For example, here is a second complete snippet that requires no boilerplate, and requires no empty instance declarations:

```
bar :: Foo m => String -> m Int
bar id = foo id

-- all the remaining code is copied from the question

class Foo m where
  foo :: String -> m Int

instance Foo IO where
  foo _ = return 0
```

You may still have `bar` behave differently than `foo`; the price you pay is that the way its behavior differs from `foo` must be the same for all types (i.e. you can't have one type with a custom `bar` implementation), but perhaps that's not a bad price in your case.